# Why does this cin loop never end?

Tags: c++, iostream

In the following code, if the user inputs something that is not an `int`, the program goes into an infinite loop.  Why does this happen, and what should I do to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[100];
    while (!(cin >> i))
    {
        gets(str);
        cout << "failure read!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "successful read!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not right? Please be specific.

Comment: Please restate your question in the form of a question.

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?  Just asking "what is wrong" and posting the code requires that we fire up our compiler and test it out, which isn't terribly helpful for people answering your question.  Having a vague title makes it hard for people who have this problem in the future to find your question.  Having no description of the problem scenario makes it difficult for people who have this problem to determine if your question is the same as theirs.

Comment: You're trying to mix iostream and stdio input from the same source?

Comment: I think he want to stay in the while loop while the user don't write an integer outputting `"failure read!"` and when he read an integer the program just outputs `"succesful read!"`.

Comment: @NoviceCai: is what I said above what you want??

Comment: Your while loop is not testing for success of >>, but for whether cin has had a failure (>> returns the istream cin).  Once one cin >> i has failed, cin is in a failed state and you never get out of the loop

I inserted some code before and after the while to demonstrate

    `cout << "fail bit: " << cin.fail() << endl;
    while (!(cin >> i))
    {
        cout << "fail bit: " << cin.fail() << endl;
        gets(str);
        cout << "failure read!" << endl;
    }`

Comment: Your while loop is not testing for success of >>, but for whether cin has had a failure (>> returns the istream cin).  Once one cin >> i has failed, cin is in a failed state and you never get out of the loop<br/>

I inserted some code before and after the while to demonstrate<br/>

`cout << "fail bit: " << cin.fail() << endl;<br/>
while (!(cin >> i))<br/>
{<br/>
 cout << "fail bit: " << cin.fail() << endl;<br/>
 gets(str);<br/>
 cout << "failure read!" << endl;<br/>
}<br/>`

Comment: Thank you DWright.  I want to read a number from keyboard. If a non-number input happened, it will keep reading it.

Comment: Sorry about formatting.  I couldn't figure out how to get line-breaks.

Comment: Incidentally, Murilo understood the question, and so did I.  I don't think it was so hard to understand.  Oh well.

Comment: @Novice: I edited your question to include the gist of your comment: non-numeric input causes infinite loop.  These details are useful; you should share them!

Comment: @DWright: I understood and knew how to solve the problem.  It just was a poorly asked question, and I felt worth closing for that reason.  This is both a Q&A site *and* a reference site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the error state:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char str[100];
    while (!(cin >> i))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.getline(str,100);
        cout << "failure read!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "successful read!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to replace the while loop with an if statement,  with this loop, you'll continuously read from cin while an error occurs.  However, cin is structured so that after an error occurs, you must manually clear the error state, and since you're not doing that here this will go into an infinite loop.  Using an if statement tries to read a value and then let's you know whether or not it succeeded.

Additionally, this really isn't a good way to read from cin.  It's brittle and any invalid input can totally take down your program, since gets is inherently unsafe.  For a discussion of a safer and more robust way to get input in C++, check out http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf

Comment: this answer is not what I want.

Comment: @NoviceCai: If you don't want an answer which explains what's wrong and a better approach, **why did you ask the question?**

Comment: No. I mean I want an answer. But what you said is not what I want. Sorry